# How can I reverse a each column of a matrix

Tags: c++

I want to change the a matrix

A=[[1,2],[3,4]] to A'=[[3,4],[1,2]]

How can I write a C++ program to make this change

Here is my attempt. but it fails
Here I am declaring a global variable g=0
and at each iteration I am trying to reverse each row

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int g=0;
void rotaterow(vector<vector<int>>&matrix, int a, int j)
{
int n = matrix.size();
 int k=n-1;
for (int i = 0; i < n/2; i++)
{
    int s=matrix[a][g];
    int b=matrix[k][g];
    swap(matrix[a][i], matrix[k--][j]);
}
g++;// taking g as a global variable
//matrix[a][n - 1] = temp;
}



int main()
{
int n;
cin>>n;
vector<vector<int>>matrix(n, vector<int>(n));
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
    {
        cin>>matrix[i][j];
    }
}

for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
rotaterow(matrix,0,j);

for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
    cout<<matrix[i][j]<<" ";
    cout<<endl;
}
}
```

Comment: use `std::swap()`?

Comment: *"but it fails"* -- fails how? Did it manage to prove that one equals zero? *If it failed compiling, you should give the error message in the question. If it produced the wrong result, you should provide the actual result (in addition to the expected result, which you already did).*

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't mention any specific problem with your program, you can use `std::swap` as shown below:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> vec = {{1,2,3}, {4,5,6}};
    std::cout<<"before swap: "<<std::endl;
    for(std::vector<std::vector<int>>::size_type row = 0; row < vec.size(); ++row)
    {
        for(std::vector<int>::size_type col = 0; col < vec.at(row).size(); ++col)
        {
            std::cout<<vec.at(row).at(col)<<" ";
        }
        std::cout<<std::endl;
    }
    //swap the 0th and 1st column
    std::swap(vec.at(0), vec.at(1));
    
    std::cout<<"after swap: "<<std::endl;
    for(std::vector<std::vector<int>>::size_type row = 0; row < vec.size(); ++row)
    {
        for(std::vector<int>::size_type col = 0; col < vec.at(row).size(); ++col)
        {
            std::cout<<vec.at(row).at(col)<<" ";
        }
        std::cout<<std::endl;
    }
}
```

The output of the above program can be seen [here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/whKqE41T8opUOzUJ).